# iOS facebook graph api comments

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Is there way to fetch facebook comments with graph api without logging. When user is logged in comments can be fetch without problem, first I fetch user comment box object from web and after that make second request with id of comment box. If user is logged out in first request completition handler returns error The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "http://testapi.club/test.php", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
        request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print(result)
                let og_object = (result as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["og_object"]
                let objecId = (og_object as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["id"]
                let requestForComments = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(objecId!)/comments", parameters: ["summary": "true","filter": "toplevel", "order":"chronological"], HTTPMethod: "GET")
                requestForComments.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error.description)
                    }else {
                        print(result)
                    }
                })
            }else{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need an access token to request any data from the API (apart from profile pictures). So you either need to make your users log in, so that you can use their access token - or you need to use a different kind of access token (app or page), if the content is accessible using those. But be aware that those should never be exposed in client-side code - so if you want to do it that way, you have to do it server-side.

Comment: Tnx, I figure it out. Just send App ID| App Secret
 for token to get comment box object and after that send request with graphPath  /"objecId"/comments and same token.

Comment: Did you do it server-side then? (Otherwise you put your app and its users at a huge risk.)